# Get list of strings between certain strings in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, cut

Given a text file (.tex) which may contain strings of the form "\cite{alice}", "\cite{bob}", and so on, I would like to write a bash script that stores the content within brackets of each such string ("alice" and "bob") in a new text file (say, .txt).
In the output file I would like to have one line for each such content, and I would also like to avoid repetitions.

**Attempts:**

- I thought about combining grep and cut.
  From other questions and answers that I have seen on Stack Exchange I think that (modulo reading up on cut a bit more) I could manage to get at least one such content per line, but I do not know how to get all occurences of a single line if there are several such strings in it and I have not seen any question or answer giving hints in this direction.
- I have tried using sed as well. Yesterday I read [this guide](https://linuxhandbook.com/sed-reference-guide/) to see if I was missing some basic sed command, but I did not see any straightforward way to do what I want (the guide did mention that sed is Turing complete, so I am sure there is a way to do this only with sed, but I do not see how).

Comment: Edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve the problem. Verbal descriptions don't help diagnose your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\\cite{)[^}]+(?=})' sample.tex | sort -u > cites.txt
```

- **`-P`** with **GNU `grep`** interprets the regexp as a Perl-compatible one (for **lookbehind** and **lookahead** groups)
- **`-o`** *"prints **only** the **matched** (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a **separate** output **line**"* (see [manual](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html))
- The **regexp** matches a curly-brace-free text preceded by `\cite{` (**positive lookbehind** group `(?<=\\cite{)`) and followed by a right curly brace (**positive lookafter** group `(?=})`).
- **`sort -u`** sorts and remove duplicates

---

For more details about lookahead and lookbehind groups, see [Regular-Expressions.info dedicated page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately there are still 2 issues. har77/km98 were just examples, so I think the solution should involve some regular expression like .* instead. But then the output contains lines such as \cite{har77} [...] \cite{km98}. The other remaining issue is to get rid of \cite{} and output only har77 instead of \cite{har77}. I can only think of unefficient ways to do this, perhaps there is some way to do it directly that I am missing

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you very much for your nice explanations as well, I found them very helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Nice to hear it was understandable

Comment: `grep -P` is very nice, but not portable.

Comment: @tripleee, yes, it works with the GNU version. Since OP tagged the question as `bash`, I suppose it's in the scope though.

Comment: Your shell does not at all influence which other utilities are installed, and Bash is installed in a lot of places where GNU `grep` is not (MacOS for one common example).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -o` and postprocess its output:

```
grep -o '\\cite{[^{}]*}' file.tex |
sed 's/\\cite{\([^{}]*\)}/\1/'
```

If there can only ever be a single `\cite` on an input line, just a `sed` script suffices.

```
sed -n 's/.*\\cite{\([^{}]*\)}.*/\1/p' file.tex
```

(It's by no means impossible to refactor this into a script which extracts multiple occurrences per line; but good luck understanding your code six weeks from now.)

As usual, add `sort -u` to remove any repetitions.

Here's a brief Awk attempt:

```
awk -v RS='\' '/^cite\{/ {
    split($0, g, /[{}]/)
    cite[g[2]]++ }
  END { for (cit in cite) print cit }' file.tex
```

This conveniently does not print any duplicates, and trivially handles multiple citations per line.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! Your first code produces the following error: sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Oh sorry -- try now. Dang mobile keyboard.